# Why is React Redux Form, not passing the formState for SELECT options?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-redux-form

Below is a relevant code snippet. I'm using redux form to render a Select Field... When the field renders, when you change the select option, the form's state is never changed.

```
console.log(this.props.formState)
```

The above always renders as undefined. What am I doing wrong?

```
let SelectGroup = ({input, title, label, type, defaultOption, options, meta: {touched, error, pristine}}) =>
    <select>
      {options.map(o =>
        <option key={o.id} value={o.id}>{o.title}</option>
      )}
    </select>
render() {
   console.log(this.props.formState)

    ....
        <Field
          component={ SelectGroup }
          name={ 'industry_id' }
          title={ 'industry_id' }
          options={ this.props.industries }
        />

  }
}



PlacePage = reduxForm({
  form: 'PlacePageForm',
  validate,
})(PlacePage);

const selector = formValueSelector('PlacePageForm')

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    formState: getFormValues('PlacePageForm')(state),
    selected_industry_id: selector(state, 'industry_id'),
    ....
  };
};




export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PlacePage);
```

Comment: Hard to tell from example, but if you're going to setup your own custom component and pass it to the `<Field/>` component than you are responsible for implementing the input hooks. Here's the faq info on this from the redux-form docs http://redux-form.com/6.6.3/docs/faq/CustomComponent.md/

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved by changing:

```
<select>
```

to:

```
<select {...input}>
```